# Detect click on resize window UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, titlebar

I would like to launch a message dialog at the click of the resize button..

I inserted the message dialog in any click, but how can I launch it in the resize window?

[image: Resize button]

The code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("This is a Message dialog");
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

I approached a possible solution but, I just need the resize button click, is it possible?

The code:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += (ss, ee) =>
{
      var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
      if (appView.IsFullScreen)
      {
          //show message
      }
      ee.Handled = true;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can subscribe to Page Size changed event for this

**XAML**

```
<Page
x:Class="App.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SO15"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged"> <!-- SizeChanged event -->
```

**C#**

```
private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += async (ss, ee) =>
    {
        var appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        if (appView.IsFullScreen)
        {
            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Window is Maximized");
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        ee.Handled = true;
    };
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += async (ss, ee) =>
    {
        var appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        if (!appView.IsFullScreen)
        {
            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Window is not Maximized");
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();

        }
        ee.Handled = true;
    };
}
```

**Alternately handle it in c# Recommended**

using this event

**`Window.Current.CoreWindow.SizeChanged += CoreWindow_SizeChanged;`**

```
bool msgboxshown = false; //add this condition in above solution also if msg dialog shown multiple times at the time of mazimizing window

    private async void CoreWindow_SizeChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
    {            
        var appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

        if (!appView.IsFullScreen && !msgboxshown)
        {
            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Window is not maximized");
            msgboxshown = true;                
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            msgboxshown = false;
        }

        if (appView.IsFullScreen && !msgboxshown)
        {
            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Windows is maximized");
            msgboxshown = true;                
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            msgboxshown = false;

        }
        args.Handled = true;
    }

/* You can remove msgboxshown condition , it is because message dialog  will show continuously multiple times  */
```

Comment: Note: IsFullScreen and IsFullScreenMode are different, IsFullScreen is for Maximized (the button at the top-right), and IsFullScreenMode is for Full Screen (Windows Key + shift + enter).

Comment: The link to MS doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.isfullscreen?view=winrt-19041
We should just use AdjacentToLeftDisplayEdge and AdjacentToRightDisplayEdge to detect maximized in SizeChanged event..