# Is there any way to capture a user clicking the "maximize" button on a UWP app?

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to find a clean way to put my app into full-screen mode (as opposed to maximized mode) when the user clicks the maximize button.  The problem is, I can't find any event to identify when the maximize button is clicked.

The reason I'm asking this question is I have a UWP game that runs in FullScreenMode.  However, if the user wants to switch it windowed mode, they can.  If they want to go back to Full Screen Mode again, there is no way for me to tell that they're trying to request that.

I could add a button on the game, but that feels pretty cheesy.

Comment: This one works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610112/detect-click-on-resize-window-uwp

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if its still relevant, but I found a sort of a solution.
All window size change ways that I tried (manual change, maximize/restore down/pinning the window to a screen edge) cause the **CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().SizeChanged** event to fire.

I also found out that clicking on the maximize/restore down button, unlike the other size changing ways, does not invoke **CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().ResizeStarted** and **CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().ResizeCompleted**.

So, a possible way to identify a maximize click, is to add a boolean variable (initialized as false), that is set when **ResizeStarted** is invoked, and reset when **ResizeCompleted** is invoked, and whenever **SizeChanged** is invoked, check for the boolean to know if the window size was changed manually, or by clicking on maximize/restore down.

Comment: I've pretty much abandoned this requirement, but when I have a chance to crack open that code again, I'll give this a try.  I'm still not sure why such a basic event isn't being tracked by UWP.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific event to identify maximize button. But, you can find it by using **sizechanged** event for your page or frame. Then use ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsFullScreen to identify the window is maximized.

**Edit:** use **IsFullScreenMode** instead of **IsFullScreen**. IsFullScreen verfies only whether the window touches the left and right side of the display.

```
  public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();
        YourPage.SizeChanged += YourPage_SizeChanged;
    }

    private  void YourPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsFullScreenMode)
        {
            WindowButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            FullScreenButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            FullScreenButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            WindowButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
    private void WindowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().ExitFullScreenMode();
    }

    private void FullScreenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    }
```

Comment: That only 'sort of' works.  
IsFullScreen seems to return true if not maximized but still full screen.

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to put the window into Full Screen Mode when the user clicks on the maximize button.  Your solution provides that, but the side effect is that the window cannot ever be brought out of full screen mode.  As soon as you click the windowed mode button, the window shifts from Full Screen Mode to windowed, but the size still fills the screen, triggering the code to enter Full Screen Mode again.

Comment: I've updated my original question with more details on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay i get it you need to change the button based on screen size you are in. If user is in full screen mode you need to switch to window mode in other case switch to fullscreen mode. Okay i will edit the answer.

Comment: I really do appreciate the effort, but this won't work.  It looks like you're suggesting that I add buttons to the game to give me full screen/windowed operations.  That's not what I'm looking for.  I want to be able to use the native windows buttons.

Answer (score 1):

> In my case, I'm trying to put the window into Full Screen Mode when the user clicks on the maximize button. Your solution provides that, but the side effect is that the window cannot ever be brought out of full screen mode. As soon as you click the windowed mode button, the window shifts from Full Screen Mode to windowed, but the size still fills the screen, triggering the code to enter Full Screen Mode again.

@Paul Mouchet There's no built-in APIs for you. It's a **Feature Request**. I've helped you submit it on [WPDev UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/36297325-need-a-way-to-capture-a-user-clicking-the-maximiz).

Comment: Thanks Xavier.  I didn't know that Developer Feedback forum existed.